# Ensure that azure service bus connects via HTTPS, not HTTP

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I would like to find an elegent way to ensure that my self-hosted web services connect to Azure Service Bus (topics and queues) via HTTPS - I don't want them falling back to HTTP.

```
// this ensures that HTTP is used instead of TCP sockets.
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```

The above setting to ensures that TCP sockets aren't attempted, but I cannot find any way of making sure that HTTP fallback isn't used in the case of a failure to set up HTTPS (SSL).

My proxy stops fiddler from working nicely with the service bus, so when I bring up fiddler it just records a bunch of (unencrypted) HTTP traffic going out from my servers - obviously this is the opposite of what I want.

The messaging entities expect to be passed a URI in the shape of

```
 Endpoint=sb://somenamespace.servicebus.windows.net/; ...
```

Which prevents me from specifying *https://....* . Does anyone have any ideas of how and where I can forbid Service Bus from using unencrypted communications?

---

Interestingly (inconsistently?), the namespace manager doesn't seem to mind using a URL with https in it ...

```
var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(
  "Endpoint=https://somenamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;..."
);
```

---

Update #1 : Booting up wireshark, looks like the communication going is through port 80. It uses http 1.1 streams, which explains why fiddler and the proxy didn't play nicely. A handshake takes place where azure sends a webstream address in a 201 response, and then TCP packets start getting passed over port 80, including information in the clear like the following:

```
*sb://somenamespace.servicebus.windows.net:80/....application/ssl-tls
...
(later on)
... 
http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/MSIT%20Machine%20Auth%20CA%202(1).crt
```

This makes me strongly suspect that TLS traffic is being sent through port 80 - though I'd like for someone to be able to confirm this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a few presentations on Azure [ [1](http://windowsazuredownunder.azurewebsites.net/watk/Presentations/WindowsAzureServiceBus/WindowsAzureServiceBus.pptx), [2](http://www.slideshare.net/michelebusta/global-windows-azure-bootcamp-san-diego) ]:

If TCP ports 9350-9353 are blocked:

- Listeners listen via outbound HTTP (Port 80). "TCP equivalent tunnel with overlaid TLS/SSL formed over a pair of HTTP requests."
- Senders send via outbound HTTPS (Port 443).

This matches up with my observations from wireshark. It doesn't appear that Azure Service Bus has a non-encrypted fallback for brokered messaging - even when it falls back to port 80 the communication remains encrypted via TLS/SSL.

Comment: Port numbers have changed. The new library uses AMQP and different port numbers: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/11/07/open-port-requirements-and-ip-address-whitelisting/